# Converting frame to bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

I am using MediaCodec to decode H264 frames on Android, but instead of using a surface as target, I receive the decoded frames as a byte array. The problem is these frames are in different Color space formats (Yuv planar, Yuv semiplanar...) depending on the device.

If I want to display this myself into a Bitmap within an app, how can I properly take care of this color conversion into RGB or ARGB which Bitmap supports?

Specifically, I would like the end result of my decoding to be a ARGB8888 bitmap image.

Is it possible to achieve this directly with MediaCodec? Do I have to do all these conversions in software?